# How to apply one of three different CSS files on the same webpage based on selection of a link in MasterPage?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a Master Page which has 3 links.

```
<a id="REDColor" href="WebForm1.aspx?name=Red">Red</a>
   <a id="GREEN" href="WebForm1.aspx">Green</a>
   <a id="BLUE" href="WebForm1.aspx">Blue</a>
```

All these links direct to the same webform1.aspx.

I have three Css files having different background colors;

RED.css

```
body {
    background-color:red;}
```

GREEN.CSS

```
body {
        background-color:green;}
```

BLUE.Css

```
    body {
 background-color:blue;}
```

How should I link these CSS files to the individual links in the Master page so that the appropriate Css file is applied to the Webform.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= name %>.css">
```

You may try to include css files by using variable in WebForm1.aspx like this.